# Docker ruby container with smashing - load Error

Tags: ruby, docker

I created a Dockerfile, which is the following

```
FROM ruby:2.2.3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app


RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install nodejs && \
    apt-get -y clean

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install
RUN bundle update

COPY ./dashboards ./dashboards
COPY ./widgets ./widgets
COPY ./jobs ./jobs
COPY ./config ./config
COPY ./config.ru .
COPY ./lib ./lib
COPY ./assets ./assets

ENV PORT 3030
EXPOSE $PORT

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

I can't run [smashing](https://github.com/Smashing/smashing) in a Docker container. I get a LoadError. The Gemfile just references smashing to install the required packages. Unfortunately, if I start my container and run `smashing start`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/src/app/jobs/scheduler.rb:4:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /usr/src/app/lib/imelk_service/imelkCalls.rb (LoadError)
    from /usr/src/app/jobs/scheduler.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/backports-3.11.3/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/backports-3.11.3/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require_with_backports'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/smashing-1.1.0/lib/dashing/app.rb:169:in `block in require_glob'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/smashing-1.1.0/lib/dashing/app.rb:168:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/smashing-1.1.0/lib/dashing/app.rb:168:in `require_glob'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/smashing-1.1.0/lib/dashing/app.rb:179:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/smashing-1.1.0/lib/dashing.rb:3:in `require'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/smashing-1.1.0/lib/dashing.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from config.ru:1:in `require'
    from config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:182:in `load_rackup_config'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:72:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:203:in `run_command'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:159:in `run!'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/thin:16:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/thin:16:in `<main>'
```

I'm trying to figure out why. I checked that file `ìmelkCalls.rb` exists. Outside of Docker, my code runs, so it can't be that. I'm guessing it's some missing dependencies, but I have no clue which one this could be. I tried it with Ruby versions 2.5 and 2.3, but I get the same error.

Hopefully, someone has an idea on what I'm doing wrong or could point me in the right direction.

Additional information that might be usefull (from within the Docker container):

ruby version: ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]

gem version: 2.5.0

bundler version: Bundler version 1.10.6

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    backports (3.11.3)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    daemons (1.2.6)
    et-orbi (1.1.0)
      tzinfo
    eventmachine (1.2.5)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    mustermann (1.0.2)
    rack (2.0.5)
    rack-protection (2.0.1)
      rack
    rufus-scheduler (3.4.2)
      et-orbi (~> 1.0)
    sass (3.4.25)
    sinatra (2.0.1)
      mustermann (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-protection (= 2.0.1)
      tilt (~> 2.0)
    sinatra-contrib (2.0.1)
      backports (>= 2.0)
      multi_json
      mustermann (~> 1.0)
      rack-protection (= 2.0.1)
      sinatra (= 2.0.1)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    smashing (1.1.0)
      coffee-script (~> 2.4.1)
      execjs (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 2.0.0)
      rufus-scheduler (~> 3.4.2)
      sass (~> 3.4.24)
      sinatra (~> 2.0.0)
      sinatra-contrib (~> 2.0.0)
      sprockets (~> 3.7.1)
      thin (~> 1.7.0)
      thor (~> 0.19.4)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    thin (1.7.2)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.4)
      rack (>= 1, < 3)
    thor (0.19.4)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  smashing

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a naming mistake in your directory structure which results in your error.

Unfortunately, persons who don't have access to the repository are not able to resolve your error.

To be clear the file (which smashing is looking for) `lib/imelk_service/imelkCalls.rb` is named `lib/imelk_service/ImelkCalls.rb` (mark the capital I letter from Imelk).
I updated your code and pushed it back into the repository.

Kind regards,

Marvyn